# how to write findOneAndUpdate query in express.js?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

i have shown  my data , which is stored in database like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5799995943d643600fabd6b7"
    },
    "Username": "xx",
    "Email": "xx@gmail.com",
    "Info": "Deactivate",
    "Description": "aajdjdjddjdkjddjdjdhdj",
    "VerificationCode": "594565",
    "VerificationExpires": {
        "$date": "2016-10-07T10:20:20.077Z"
    }

}
```

My controller:

if Username, Email, Info are matched I need to update " Info = 'Active' " this is working at the same time i need to delete 'VerificationCode' field and 'VerificationExpires' field how can i achieve this?

```
exports.updatearticle = function(req, res) {
    Article.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "Username":'xx', "Email":'xx@gmail.com', "Info": "Deactivate" },
        { "$set": { "Info": "Active" } },
        { "new": true }
        function (err, doc) {
            if (err) { // err: any errors that occurred
                console.log(err);
            } else { // doc: the document before updates are applied if `new: false`
                console.log(doc); // , the document returned after updates if `new  true`
                console.log(doc.Info);
            }

        }
    );
};
```

above condtion matched and info getting changed but i want to delete VerificationCode,VerificationExpires some one help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    exports.updatearticle = function(req, res) {
    Article.findOne( { "Username":'xx', "Email":'xx@gmail.com', "Info": "Deactivate" }, function(err, result){
       if (!err && result) {
        result.Info = "Active"; // update ur values goes here
        result.VerificationCode = "";
        result.VerificationExpires = {};
        var article = new Article(result);
        article.save(function(err, result2){
            if(!err) {
               res.send(result2);
            } else res.send(err);
        })  

       } else res.send(err);
    });  
  }


 home this may help
```

Comment: getting error F:\app\test\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:413
        throw err;
        ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: in ur function there may be two time res.send() is executing, once u sent res.send() then dnt run any other codes, share me ur code once again

Comment: sorry, i was missing one else, i have added, now u can use it

Comment: findOneAndUpdate function and what i have given both will work same manner, so you can use whatever i shared,  bcz u cnt modify based on my ans, findOneAndUpdate and findOne function has differennt syntax